# How do I make AND or OR expressions?

Tags: objective-c, boolean-expression

I wrote this:

```
if( a == -11 && b == -1 ){
{

if( a == -1) AND ( b == -1)...
```

But neither work, and I have the same problem with `OR`. How do I write expressions that include `OR` or `AND`?

Answer (score 23):

You use `&&` for “and”, and `||` for “or”.

Answer (score 7):

`(a == -11 && b == -1)` is fine and correct.  Objective-C uses all of the same logical operators as C. `||` is the logical-or operator.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (a==-11 && b==-1) {
```

if perfectly legal in C, and therefore Objective-C.

Your second example is not C or Objective-C