# How do you do an if statement with two true statements in objective c

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make AND or OR expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118338/how-do-i-make-and-or-or-expressions)

I know that in Java it is &&.  What is it in Objective-C.  Either that is wrong or my other code isn't working because it isn't doing the boolean. So real quick what is it?

Comment: yeah, that is the same thing.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is for an "AND" statement is: (statement && statement)

The syntax for an "OR" statement is: (statement || statement)

Sounds like your other code might be the problem.

You can also combine these statements into things like

```
((true || false) && (true || false))

//in this example it simplifies to  
(true) && (false)

(false)
```

Comment: Okay, thank alot... I'll look into trying to fix my other code. I'm a noob.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition1 && condition2) {
    // code executes only if both conditions are true
}

if (condition3 || condition4) {
    // code executes if either condition is true
}
```